# Codeigniter and facebook php sdk autopost to company wall

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have built a site with codeigniter and implemented facebook login for users. Everything is working great there. App is connected user tokens beig saved the whole nine yards. What I am having trouble doing is having the website itself NOT the logged in user post to the connected company facebook page on a user post completion. essentially the user posts a listing. the website then on submit of that posting posts to my facebook company page NOT the logged in users facebook wall. (i have that working already. Can i leave the website logged into Facebook to post to the wall while a user is logged on as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the Appid, App secret and an access token. You can extend the access token so that it doesn't expire.

```
$graphUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APPID .'&client_secret='.APPSECRET.'&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token='.ACCESS_TOKEN;

$accessToken = @file_get_contents($graphUrl);
parse_str($accessToken); //get the access_token param in the string and would be named $access_token
if(!$access_token) $access_token = $accessToken; //if cannot be extended then just return the access token with 2 hours expiry
```

In order to post as your company page, you will need their page id.

Here is part of my script that I used to get all this working. Its not codeigniter, but you will be able to see how it works.

```
$config = array(
        'appId' => APPID,
        'secret' => APPSECRET,
);


        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $facebook->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Get User ID
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

        try {
                $page_id = '************'; // 
                $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
                if(!empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
                        // do your code stuff

                 }

         } catch etc etc
```

Hope this is helpful to you